# Old GPS coordinates sent by Android application

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

We have Android application that every 10 seconds send to our server GPS coordinates of user.
In application there are pace where you can see last coordinate that server got from app.

Some users complain they see old coordinates in that page BUT with fresh timestamp. It means app sends coordinates to server, but send old coordinates.

Could it be `LocationManager` problem or I need search problem in code?

I set log and for few test phones GPS works normal.

Comment: You need to be more specific here. How do you get the Location updates? Add some relevant code snippets.

Comment: From my experience, sometimes it can take some time for GPS to get coordinates or it cannot get them at all. If that happens the GPS system returns the old GPS location, which can be hours old, not even from your application, but the last coordinates that your phone got.

Comment: @SteveBenett I can give you only PHP code of backend, cause I'm PHP developer, but think it will not help for this question.

Comment: @Marko I hope to hear something like it) But didn't find any bug tracker with it or article about it.

Comment: @Narek It sounds that you aren't aware of the code for getting the location updates from Android side. But what you describe isn't a backend problem. It's about how the LocationManager or the FusedLocationProvider is used to get an accurate position. Without that information there's no effective way to solve your problem.

Comment: @SteveBenett yes I hope to find problem in GPS side, not in code side. If problem in code then I'm just losing time.